# How to transport a giant troll across a frozen lake?

Tags: mythical-creatures, transportation, sports

Every winter the villagers will organize a troll hunting sport for team building, the party will head toward the forest in search for a 30m tall humanoid creature and hunt it down.

These creatures are social creature and feed on wild animals, they tend to avoid people but would become aggressive when provoked.

Allow me to cut to the chase, the village hunters managed to kill a troll as heavy as 5 adult African elephants, in order to validate that the hunt is successful they must bring the carcass back to the village which is at the opposite side of the frozen lake (roughly 100 Olympic size swimming pools) intact(yes you must blame on their superstitious nature and this is part of their ritual requirement).

How can they bring the carcass with head and all the limbs still attached to the torso back to the village in the 5th century times?

Comment: What kind of troll are we talking about? Eg. DnD Trolls weight about 500lb, same as about 3 humans, that wouldnt be a problem to transport on ice given the ice is thick enough to carry a human. http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Troll

Comment: @Magic-Mouse: the troll is 30 meters tall and weight approximately 40000kg on average.

Comment: How thick is the ice?

Comment: @HowardMiller: varies as there are people cutting holes to fish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best method of transport would likely be just to get it rolling over logs being pulled by rope, a few people moving the rearmost log to the front as they go. The thickness of the ice would decide if they can simply move it over the lake or if they'd have to go around (which is the only other option assuming magic is not an option, which I only mention due to it being a mythological creature).

Here's a visual representation for what I mean if you need it:
http://www.thunderboltkids.co.za/Grade5/03-energy-and-change/images/gd-0057.png

Comment: I thought sliding over the ice requires least effort than rolling :)

Comment: Might be, but if the ice is thick enough to walk over with a 40,000kg troll I'd have went with the assumption that it is frozen year round or at least long enough for snow to build up over it, so it wouldn't be perfectly smooth and even the slightest friction would be more effort than rolling.

Comment: Logs are definitely the way to go. Then you need not only good hunters, but also great lumberjacks. 40kkg spread out over a 30m x 30m square is quite manageable...it might even float.

Answer (score 1):

[Dead bodies float, typically](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2005/09/dead_mans_float.html) so it depends on what the troll is made of. If the troll is made up of mostly meat, it should likely float (especially once it starts rotting a little), and at best, or worst, they could add wooden outriders.

So patch up any holes in the chest, plug up that big ol maw and nose, and slide the big ol beastie into the water. They can go ahead and break up ice as needed

Then they can sit on the troll and row or drag. If the ice is thick enough, then just slide the troll across.

Answer (score 1):

Ice thickness really makes a difference here.  A foot of ice can hold a decent sized pickup truck on 4 tires.  3000-4000 pounds.  A foot of ice really isn't that bad, here in MN during a cold winter it can be over 4' thick.

One thing about ice and how much weight it can support is a per inch calculation.  So a large beast laying on the ice will be spreading it's weight out over a much larger area than just it's two/four feet.

So first prepare the lake, make a canal through any snow to reduce friction. next get long ropes, and tie up the beast.  Then have everyone haul on the ropes way out in front of the beast, so even if it cracks the ice it should still float in the water and be able to be pulled along.

Now if the beast is very dense, then you would need to build a large platform to haul it on that would distribute the weight out over a much larger area of the ice.  Since this is a yearly ritual, then it only needs to be made once and reused every year with what ever repairs need to be made.

Of course getting the beast to the lake or on a sled is still going to be a huge undertaking.  Just removing the head and bringing it would be undertaking.  a 40,000Kg being would have a head still in the rage of 2,000 KG by itself.

(and what are they going to do with a huge troll body after they get it to the village?  eat it?  The head alone will be a big enough mess to deal with)

Comment: Great point about being able to drive a car on ice. I think the platform is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Any conceivable thickness of ice is going to crack, even if they try to lay the troll out flat and slide it across.

If the troll's density is even just slightly less  than water, you might use it's head as an icebreaker and float it across the lake. Or they could cut a channel from one side of the lake to the other, and float the troll along the channel. Beasts of burden could walk alongside on the ice, pulling it along.

I thought about cutting trees to make a giant sledge to move the troll, but I think that would just make the problem worse. Of course, if trolls tend to sink, then making a barge for it might be the answer.

Cutting ice in large blocks and storing them in a warehouse is a very old practice. Large blocks can outlast a summer, so if the villagers had rights to the ice in the lake, they'd probably do that regularly. Ice in summer is a valuable commodity.

Comment: Do you mean moving the jaw of the troll and let the teeth cut into the ice or headbutt? I like your answer use the troll as ice breaker :)

Comment: @user6760 I was thinking more along the lines of a headbutt. The troll's dead, it's not going to get a headache. For some reason I think of the troll as being bald.

Answer (score 0):

I propose carrying it across on a runner sled with iced runners.

From https://world-records.org/largest-sled/

> The largest sledge measures 10 m (32 ft 9 in) long, 4 m (13 ft 1 in)
>   wide and 3.1 m (10 ft 2 in) tall. The sledge was made by the tourism
>   association of Bergün, Switzerland and pulled through the village on 4
>   February 2006.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sled

> Sleds and sledges were found in the Oseberg "Viking" ship excavation.
>   Sledges were useful not only in winter but can be drawn over wet
>   fields, muddy roads, and even hard ground, if one helps them along by
>   greasing the blades with oil or alternatively wetting them with water;
>   in cold weather the water will freeze to ice and they glide along more
>   smoothly with less effort to pull them

At 30 meters its legs would drag behind but the center of mass would be ok on the big sledge and the dragging legs would not produce that much friction.  Or you could hogtie it.

I also propose that the troll first be gutted in the manner of any other large animal taken in a hunt.  It will be a lot lighter without the guts, lungs, heart etc and it will still have head and all limbs attached as required in OP.